# Cannot Install, Update Software in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade, software-installation, updates

I couldnot able to install or update my software in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Here is the problem:

```
akhil@KHUSHI:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic
The following packages have been kept back:
  gnome-remote-desktop tzdata
The following packages will be upgraded:
  code google-chrome-stable libldb2 liblouis-data liblouis20
  libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0 libpulse0:i386 libpulsedsp libsmbclient
  libwbclient0 microsoft-edge-dev pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
  pulseaudio-utils python3-ldb python3-louis samba-libs sudo vim-common
  vim-tiny xxd
22 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 342 MB of archives.
After this operation, 8,337 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable/main amd64 code amd64 1.77.3-1681292746 [88.5 MB]
Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 python3-ldb amd64 2:2.4.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 [41.7 kB]
Get:3 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 google-chrome-stable amd64 112.0.5615.49-1 [93.8 MB]
Get:4 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable/main amd64 microsoft-edge-dev amd64 114.0.1788.0-1 [147 MB]
Get:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libldb2 amd64 2:2.4.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 [154 kB]
Get:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libsmbclient amd64 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1.1 [65.9 kB]
Get:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libwbclient0 amd64 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1.1 [267 kB]
Get:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 samba-libs amd64 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1.1 [6,276 kB]
Get:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libpulse-mainloop-glib0 amd64 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.1 [12.4 kB]
Get:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 pulseaudio-utils amd64 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.1 [76.1 kB]
Get:11 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 pulseaudio-module-bluetooth amd64 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.1 [99.5 kB]
Get:12 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 pulseaudio amd64 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.1 [914 kB]
Get:13 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libpulsedsp amd64 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.1 [23.3 kB]
Get:14 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 libpulse0 i386 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.1 [296 kB]
Get:15 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libpulse0 amd64 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.1 [297 kB]
Get:16 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 sudo amd64 1.9.9-1ubuntu2.4 [821 kB]
Get:17 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 vim-tiny amd64 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.5 [707 kB]
Get:18 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 xxd amd64 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.5 [53.0 kB]
Get:19 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 vim-common all 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.5 [81.5 kB]
Get:20 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 liblouis-data all 3.20.0-2ubuntu0.2 [1,993 kB]
Get:21 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 liblouis20 amd64 3.20.0-2ubuntu0.2 [87.6 kB]
Get:22 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 python3-louis all 3.20.0-2ubuntu0.2 [7,490 B]
Fetched 342 MB in 1min 26s (3,981 kB/s)                                        
(Reading database ... 329778 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic (5.15.0-50.56) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-50-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_zs8jjk'.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Also If I install any new software:

```
akhil@KHUSHI:~$ sudo apt install nginx
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libnginx-mod-http-geoip2 libnginx-mod-http-image-filter
  libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter libnginx-mod-mail libnginx-mod-stream
  libnginx-mod-stream-geoip2 nginx-common nginx-core
Suggested packages:
  fcgiwrap nginx-doc
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libnginx-mod-http-geoip2 libnginx-mod-http-image-filter
  libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter libnginx-mod-mail libnginx-mod-stream
  libnginx-mod-stream-geoip2 nginx nginx-common nginx-core
0 upgraded, 9 newly installed, 1 to remove and 24 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 696 kB of archives.
After this operation, 9,177 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 nginx-common all 1.18.0-6ubuntu14.3 [40.0 kB]
Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libnginx-mod-http-geoip2 amd64 1.18.0-6ubuntu14.3 [11.9 kB]
Get:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libnginx-mod-http-image-filter amd64 1.18.0-6ubuntu14.3 [15.4 kB]
Get:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter amd64 1.18.0-6ubuntu14.3 [13.7 kB]
Get:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libnginx-mod-mail amd64 1.18.0-6ubuntu14.3 [45.7 kB]
Get:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libnginx-mod-stream amd64 1.18.0-6ubuntu14.3 [72.8 kB]
Get:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libnginx-mod-stream-geoip2 amd64 1.18.0-6ubuntu14.3 [10.1 kB]
Get:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 nginx-core amd64 1.18.0-6ubuntu14.3 [482 kB]
Get:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 nginx amd64 1.18.0-6ubuntu14.3 [3,882 B]
Fetched 696 kB in 3s (262 kB/s)
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 329778 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic (5.15.0-50.56) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-50-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_
zs8jjk'.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic package post-removal script subprocess 
returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am getting same error If I try to install new software.